# Does AWS sdk have error handling logic? If not, which sdk have error handling logic?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, sdk, aws-sdk-js

There is **no error handling** logic in the sdk that I am currently making. So when an error occurs in the API call, the error message given by the API is **just displayed to the user**.

I think sdk **needs backoff logic** (error handling, retry, etc.) for user convenience.

So I'm looking at [aws sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js). **However**, AWS sdk also seems to be simply creating an error object and displayed errors from the API.

According to my research, Forexample ...

```
// 1. When input invalidate accountId type.
var client = new AWS.S3Control().getPublicAccessBlock({AccountId : accountId}).build();
// 2. It occur error.
getPublicAccessBlock(params: ...params, callback?: (err: AWSError, data: ...data) => void): Request< ...data, AWSError>;

// 3. AWS sdk simply displayed error in AWSError object 
export type AWSError = Error & {
  code: string;
  message: string;
  retryable?: boolean;
  statusCode?: number;
  time: Date;
  hostname?: string;
  region?: string;
  retryDelay?: number;
  requestId?: string;
  extendedRequestId?: string;
  cfId?: string;
  originalError?: Error
}
```

**MyGoal is**

- **Is there an error handling logic in aws sdk?**
- **If not, which sdk is helpful with error handling logic among the other sdk?**